# React Native Picker, when an option is selected from Picker the screen goes to next screen

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, my code is like when I click "Admin" or any other category in login page and press login button the screen goes to Admin Page when admin is clicked and when "Cocordinator"  clicked then it goes to coordinator page.
This is my Picker code:

```
        <Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.role}
  style={{height: 50, width: 300}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.setState({role: itemValue})
  }>
  <Picker.Item label="Admin" value="ad" />
  <Picker.Item label="Coordinator" value="cod" />
</Picker>
```

And that is my condition:

```
  loginRoles(){
     if(this.state.Picker.Item==='Admin')
     {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminHome');
     }
     else if(this.state.Picker.Item==='Coordinator')
     {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('CoAdd');
     }
     else{
       alert("Invalid Login");
     }
   }
```

Apparently the problem is in my condition as its not reading the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the state of `role`, i.e `this.setState({role: itemValue})`

Hence, you'll have to check the value of `this.state.role`

```
if(this.state.role === 'ad')
{
  this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminHome');
}
```

Make sure that you set the initial value of role as the first value in Picker, else your handler function will jump to the else case.

i.e `this.state = {role : 'ad'}`

Comment: I suggest using arrow function for ```loginRoles()``` for automatic binding of ```this```. i.e as follows: ```loginRoles = () => { //logic goes here };```

Comment: I have tried your thing as well but when I press the login button it goes directly to else case and says "invalid login" without checking if conditions

Comment: I have edited the answer, I should have checked against the value, not label.

Comment: but 'ad' isn't defined in state as:  this.state = {
      role:['Admin', 'Coordinator'],
    }

Comment: You don't have to set the initial state as Array, use ```this.state = {role : 'ad'}```